# AppCompatSpinner custom dropdown arrow not working in Android 4.4 Samsung prime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to implement spinner with dropdown arrow.
Below is the XMl Code used:

This code works well on Android 5 and above but not on 4.4 api level 19

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerState"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xMargin_42_156"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xMargin_42_156"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_down_arrow"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:overlapAnchor="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

And background drawable as:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <!-- background color of box -->
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/my_ctl_light_gray" />
        <!-- color of stroke -->
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/drop_down_arrow"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
</item>
```

This is how it is looking:
[image]

Comment: found the solution for my own problem, use bitmap like below 
<item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:src="@drawable/drop_down_arrow" />

    </item>